# Connection of Raspberry Pi Matlab through USB

Tags: usb, home-automation

I am running one application inside Raspberry Pi. I want see the data points created by the application in graphical format in Matlab. I want to do this by connecting the computer and Raspberry Pi through USB or HDMI. I am already running this by using Ethernet cable and it is working fine, but inducing delay which is not constant. I want to minimize the delay, so going for a faster method of USB or HDMI.

Comment: Can you please add a question to your 'question'?

Comment: That's going to be quite difficult to set up.  You'd probably do better tracking down the source of delay, for example, if you are using TCP you may be suffering from the 200ms delays which the Nagle algorithm will insert into some kinds of query-response traffic patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add time stamps to your reports over ethernet, so the lags don't matter.